# How to use Systemd user services without Desktop session[No D-Bus]

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, d-bus, systemctl

I'm trying to setup user level Services(Python/Java/Node JS Processes) which need to run all the time, until I stop explicitly. The service need to be start/stopped as non root user.

I've created service file under, ~/.config/systemd/user/.
When I tried to load, **systemctl --user daemon-reload**,  it's failing with the following error.

```
$ systemctl --user daemon-reload
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory
```

I understand D-Bus won't run without Desktop session, but there is no Desktop session, it's one of the VMs provided by the Company. We don't enable Desktop sessions for the Linux servers.

```
$ ps -ef | grep systemd | grep -v grep
root          1      0  0 Jul25 ?        00:01:33 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 22
root        544      1  0 Jul25 ?        00:00:33 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root        591      1  0 Jul25 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
dbus        783      1  0 Jul25 ?        00:01:21 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
root        857      1  0 Jul25 ?        00:00:34 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
```

How do I create user level services without Desktop session ?

Answer (score 0):

It will work with just two commands.

```
cat << 'EOF' >> ~USERNAME/.profile
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)
EOF
loginctl enable-linger $USERNAME
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.

$ export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)

[root@myserver system]# loginctl enable-linger zeus

$ ls /var/lib/systemd/linger/$USERNAME
zeus

Still, fails.

$ systemctl --user daemon-reload
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory

Comment: https://imgur.com/L95Qx7p 

Tried your solution @crpb, but it didn't work.

Comment: hmm.. so no session is running for that user? i created one and  it started w/o 
 login. "testuser  469295  0.0  0.0  15396  7252 ?        Ss   05:32   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user"

Comment: Jul 31 05:32:33 intra2 useradd[469176]: new group: name=testuser, GID=2006
Jul 31 05:32:33 intra2 useradd[469176]: new user: name=testuser, UID=2006, GID=2006, home=/home/testuser, shell=/bin/zsh, from=/dev/pts/0
Jul 31 05:32:45 intra2 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user testuser(uid=2006) by (uid=0)

Comment: And as for the "applications.services". i usually just create those in another folder and enable this file with that user when everything is setup.

Comment: svc@intra2 ~/.config/systemd/user % find 
.
./default.target.wants
./default.target.wants/daphne-ifx.service
./basic.target.wants
./basic.target.wants/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
./timers.target.wants
./timers.target.wants/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
./daphne-ifx.service

Comment: Does an actual `systemctl --user enable service.desk` work?